# How can I keep a text of a div inside it and if bigger, then the div expands down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text

I'd like to know if there's a way to keep a text inside a div if the text exceeds the `width` the ´div´'s height is stretched until all the text is fitted.

**UPDATE:**

Thank y'all for helping +1, so should I use ´Inherit´ or ´min-height´?

**A plain `div`**:

[image: plain]

**Then I added a `word-wrap: break-word;`, and I've got this:**

[image: barely solved]

**The Ideal:**

[image: stretched up]

The `div`'s `height` should be increased in order to fit the **whole** text

Thanks in advance.

```css
 div {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>DIV</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>asjdkljaddddsadsssssssdfsdfsdfsf</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank y'all for helping +1, so should I use ´Inherit´ or ´min-height´?

Comment: The min-height property is used to set the minimum height of an element.
This prevents the value of the height property from becoming smaller than min-height.

Comment: inherit : Inherits this property from its parent element.

Comment: So in this case I think min-height would the best for me, but all of you were   really helpful, thank y'all

Comment: Yes, min-height is better in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `height` to `min-height` in your CSS:

The `min-height` property is used to set the minimum height of an element.

This prevents the value of the height property from becoming smaller than `min-height`.

```css
 div {
   width: 50px;
   min-height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>DIV</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>asjdkljaddddsadsssssssdfsdfsdfsf</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've chosen your answer because you were the oldest of the `min-height` answers, Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `width:inherit` for your `<div>`

This way, your `<div>` will inherit its height from the content it is enclosing

Here's the css class

```
 div {
   width: 50px;
   height: inherit;
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

and here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3cO9sw9wo9bUnpZVGRK8?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try the css lines. You can check here https://jsfiddle.net/ogd5cruf/

```
div {
   width: 50px;
   height: auto;
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change `height: 50px` to `min-height: 50px` the div's height will grow to fit it's content. Similarly, you can set a limit on the allowed height using `max-height`.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
  <div>asjdkljaddddsadsssssssdfsdfsdfsf</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
 div {
   width: 50px;
   height: 100%;
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>DIV</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>asjdkljaddddsadsssssssdfsdfsdfsf</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the fixed height

```css
 div {
   width: 50px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>DIV</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>asjdkljaddddsadsssssssdfsdfsdfsfqwqweqewqqweqweeqewqweeqw</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the div's height initially, then use:

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This will ensure it is at least 50px high, but will still expand when you put more content in it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting this issue for a long time. Here is one of pure-CSS ways to get that to work.

My example allows you to have a responsive(optionally) block of text, with a customize amount of displayed lines.

```css
// Usually you want to have that everywhere.
* {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
div {
  /* height / desired number of lines, must be higher than font-size */
  line-height: 16.66px;
  font-size: 14px;

  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
```

Comment: Interesting +1, I'm gonna implement it in my actual web app